# Node.js: Trying to redirect a user after signing up/login in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to redirect a user to his/her profile page in node after he logs in/signs up. The login/signup system is working perfectly and data is getting saved. But when the user is being redirected after signing-up or logging in, the profile page route he's being redirected to is not getting the user. Where am i going wrong? 
here is the controller on backend.

```js
var _ = require('lodash');
var {
  User
} = require('../models/user');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var validation = require('./../middlewares/validate')
var token;
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var secret = "98ix0b84gs3r@&$#*np9bgkpfjeib1f9ipe";
var decodedToken, response, err;

router.get("/users", function(req, res) {
  res.render('signup.hbs', {
    title: "New User Signup"
  });
});

router.get("/login", function(req, res) {
  res.render('login.hbs', {
    title: "New User Login"
  });
});



var authentication = (req, res, next) => {
  token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, secret, function(err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          message: 'Token authentication failed'
        });
      } else {
        decodedToken = decoded;
        console.log("Token decoded", decodedToken);
        next();
      }
    })
  }
}

router.post('/submitLogin', validation.login, function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      err = ("Something is wrong. Error= " + err);
      res.json(err);
    } else if (user === null || user === undefined || user.email === null || user.email === undefined) {
      err = ("Enter correct email");
      res.json(err);
    } else if (!user.compareHash(req.body.password)) {
      err = ("Enter correct password");
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      token = jwt.sign({
        exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60 * 60),
        id: user._id,
        email: user.email,
        username: user.username
      }, secret);

      response = {
        status: "Logged In",
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email
      };
      response.token = token; //token pushed to response
      //res.json(response);
      res.redirect('http://localhost:8000/profile/me');
    }
  });
});

router.post('/signup', validation.signup, function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
  }, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
      err = {
        error: error
      };
      res.json(err);
    } else if (user) {
      err = {
        error: "Email exists"
      };
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      var newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        user_type: "basic",
        active: true
      });
      newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(req.body.password);
      newUser.save((error) => {
        if (error) {
          response = ("Something was wrong" + error);
          res.json(response);
        } else {
          token = jwt.sign({
            exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60),
            id: newUser._id,
            email: newUser.email,
            username: newUser.username
          }, secret);

          response = {
            status: "Signed up",
            id: newUser.id,
            username: newUser.username,
            email: newUser.email
          };
          response.token = token; //token pushed to response
          //res.json(response);
          res.redirect('http://localhost:8000/profile/me/' + response.id);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});


router.get("/me/id", function(req, res) {
  User.findById({
    _id: req.params.id
  }, function(err, user) {
    console.log(user);
    if (err) {
      res.send("Please login first");
    } else {
      res.render('profile.hbs', {
        title: "New User Profile",
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email
      });
    }
  })

});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving routing information to your `/me/id` route incorrectly.

To give dynamic route parameter you need to add `:` before that variable. Replace your route

`router.get("/me/id", ...`

to

`router.get("/me/:id", ...`

you can read more about express routing [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

and other than that you are also not passing id in login method redirect. I don't know if you have another route setup for that, if not that you also need to add that.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. As for the login part, i was testing the signup part. I'll edit the login part accordingly.