# How to handle a MySQL node query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, callback

I'm trying to handle a dup key error when running a MySQL query in Node JS. I tried wrapping the call in a try-catch but there's still a crash. I also wrapped the create call in a try-catch but no luck. Does anyone how I can handle this crash?

```
create(first_name, last_name, username, email, password, callback) { 
    let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(SALT_ROUNDS);
    let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

    let sql = `INSERT INTO users (username, email, first_name, last_name, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`;
    let values = [
        username.toLowerCase(), email.toLowerCase(), 
        first_name.toLowerCase(), last_name.toLowerCase(), 
        hash
    ];

    // Crash below 
    try {
        db.query(sql, values, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                return callback(error, undefined);   
            }
            return callback(undefined, results.insertId)
        });
    } catch (error) {
        callback(error, undefined)
    }
}
```

NodeJs Route Call:

```
Users.create(first_name, last_name, username, email, password, (error, insertedId) => {
    if (error) {
        next(error);
    }
    ..
}
```

Error:

```
Database connected...
Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'test-test@gmail.com' for key 'username'
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\main\development\hvz-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\main\development\hvz-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:79:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\main\development\hvz-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\main\development\hvz-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
at Parser.write (C:\Users\main\development\hvz-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
at Protocol.write (C:\Users\main\development\hvz-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\main\development\hvz-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\main\development\hvz-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
..
..

C:\Users\main\development\hvz-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\main\development\hvz-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\main\development\hvz-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\main\development\hvz-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
```

Comment: can you show the complete error message?

Comment: @nbk definitely! I just updated the question

Comment: your field username is UNIQUE Or Primnary KEY and allows only one of a kind., you must catch the error and tell the user to enter another unsername/email or initiate the forgotten password routine

Comment: I understand but even when I wrapped it in a try-catch it still broke.

Comment: WHEN you get ER_DUP_ENTRY as error in your try catch the redirect to enter a new username(or what eve4r you want so it should be similiar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49004109/node-js-trying-to-redirect-a-user-after-signing-up-login-in-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

Since you already wrapped a try-catch around the relevant part of the code and there is still a crash, it is safe to assume that the crash happens inside the `catch`, that is, an exception is thrown from the `try` block, the `catch` block catches it and then something happens inside your `catch` block which raises another exception. You can try my theory via temporarily commenting out the code inside the `catch` just for the fun of it:

```
try {
    db.query(sql, values, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error, undefined);   
        }
        return callback(undefined, results.insertId)
    });
} catch (error) {
    //callback(error, undefined)
}
```

If it does not throw an exception now, then your call to callback raises the error and you will need to change the code inside your `catch` so that it fails gracefully.

But this is only the technical solution. Conceptually you should not even run an `insert` which might be invalid. You should perform your validation checks and if everything is cool, then run the `insert`. You will still need a try-catch around it and a proper error handling to handle the changes which happen between your validation check and your `insert` though.